# how can I do ExpandableListView in navigation drawer without using fragments?

Tags: android

So I created a expandable list view without using fragments. In my code I unable to find where is error because it's not run so here's my full code.

```
Main Activity class

package com.demo.demonavigatiodrawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.DrawerListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ImageView home;
    TextView appname;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    List<String> listDataHeader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String fontPath = "fonts/Shadow Boxing.ttf";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
        home.setOnClickListener(homeOnclickListener);
        appname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
        appname.setTypeface(tf);
        setUpDrawer();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Get the names and icons references to build the drawer menu...
     */
    private void setUpDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.transparent));
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,
                listDataChild);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    View.OnClickListener homeOnclickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(expListView)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(expListView);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(expListView);
            }
        }
    };

    private OnItemClickListener mDrawerItemClickedListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

        }
    };

    // Catch the events related to the drawer to arrange views according to this
    // action if necessary...
    private DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        }
    };

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Batsman");
        listDataHeader.add("Bowler");
        listDataHeader.add("All rounder");
        listDataHeader.add("Wicket keeper");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> batsman = new ArrayList<String>();
        batsman.add("V. Kohli");
        batsman.add("G.J. Bailey");
        batsman.add("H.M. Amla");

        List<String> bowler = new ArrayList<String>();
        bowler.add("D.W. Steyn");
        bowler.add("J.M. Anderson");
        bowler.add("M.G. Johnson");

        List<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
        all.add("R.A. Jadeja");
        all.add("Shakib Al Hasan");
        all.add("D.J. Bravo");

        List<String> wk = new ArrayList<String>();
        wk.add("A.B. de Villiers");
        wk.add("M.S. Dhoni");
        wk.add("K.C. Sangakkara");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), batsman); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), bowler);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), all);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), wk);
    }

    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,
                    childPosition);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(
                    this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
Layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DC3377"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cricket"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- Drawer Content -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <!-- The navigation menu -->

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#E6E6E6" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```css
list_group.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#F7819F">
 
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
 
</LinearLayout>
```

```css
list_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
 
</LinearLayout>
```

```css
this is my logcat error

04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.demonavigatiodrawer/com.demo.demonavigatiodrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at com.demo.demonavigatiodrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-10 12:28:13.694: E/AndroidRuntime(6847):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is issue getting crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I find out my error my self So just remove the this line..

String fontPath = "fonts/Shadow Boxing.ttf";

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
        appname.setTypeface(tf);